# Do Linux applications require proper file extentions?

Tags: linux

I use various 3rd party libraries to convert files on my Linux server.  For instance, ImageMagick/convert for images, libreoffice3.5/convert-to for Microsoft Office documents, etc.

Is it possible that these applications require the pre-converted file to have the proper extension for the type of file?  For instance, if the file was a png file, it would need to be called whatever.png and not just whatever.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your question sounds general, and in general linux apps do not require extensions. bash will execute a .png file with shell commands happily and vi will open a text file called a.exe. extensions are in general not a unix/linux concept to begin with and . is just an allowed character in the file name.

this being said, some particular application may interpret or even require correct extensions.

Comment: Thanks John,  Yea it is general.  I can tell you what I apps I am using now, but will likely use others in the future.  A little background.  I am moving files from one server to another, and it would be easier to use a random name without extension at the destination server where it will then be converted.  If there is risk, I save it with a random name with correct extension.  Recommend the later?  Thanks

Comment: it is more by convention, and extensions will help other users who may have to maintain your script/app later. While i said that bash will execute .png files happily, it is just confusing. So I would say yes the latter and trying to use an extension unless there is an overriding reason. I was talking about mostly cli. In gui file managers, I think often there are extension-based association just like in windows, such as using a picture viewer for .png/jpeg and pdf viewer for .pdf.